# Rotation of Image not working

Tags: android, imageview

I am using `imageView.setRotation(imageView.getRotation+90)` on click for rotating image it's working fine. But whenever I sending that image (Rotated Image) to the server it's showing the original view to the server not rotated the view. I'm using Retrofit multipart for sending the image.

Comment: Yes, the code only rotated the image view .you should rotate the bitmap.

Comment: post your code what you  use for rotate

Comment: @Adilhusen im using this  if (v == imgRotate) {
            pick_imageview.setRotation(pick_imageview.getRotation()+90);
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
imageView.setRotation(imageView.getRotation+90)
```

it only rotates the imageview not the content of it ,as the result bitmap remians same.

You should rotate the bitmap using

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

matrix.postRotate(90);

Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg,width,height,true);//BitmapOrg- is origanl bitmap 

Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap , 0, 0, scaledBitmap .getWidth(), scaledBitmap .getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

and

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
```

now use the `rotatedBitmap` to send the server.